# bootstrap isnt supporting on chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried including navbar from bootstrap 3.0 and it doesn't really works on Chrome.
I also included the jQuery and js src.
I wasn't able to see the navbar.
Is this happening because I didn't use the current version of bootstrap
or is it because that code has errors

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Photos Gallery
    </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"> 
<div class="container"></div>
 <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Koffee</a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <li><a href="#">about</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">home</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a> </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            signup
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            login
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `<head>` with

```
<head>
    <title>
        Photos Gallery
    </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```

> Your `<link>` is not in correct format

**Check below snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Photos Gallery
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Koffee</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

      <li><a href="#">about</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">home</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
            signup
        </a>

      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
            login
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```